# R: How can I plot the correct x-axis values in ggplot after melting the matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset, called `payoffs`.

```
dput(payoffs)
structure(c(8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -0.5, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2), .Dim = c(9L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("s", "strat1", "strat2")))
```

My goal is to plot the 2nd and 3rd  columns in 2 different lines in ggplot on the y axis and the first column will be the x-axis . So, I use `melt` function as follow:

```
m_payoffs <- melt(payoffs, id= c(2,3))
```

However, I do not know how can I plot the 2 columns "strat1" and "strat2" with the correct x-axis now ? My x-axis are suppose to be `x <- seq(8,12,by=0.5)`. Can someone kindly show me I can plot the 2 columns using ggplot while preserving the correct x-axis in ggplot please? Thanks.

```
    Var1   Var2 value
1     1      s   8.0
2     2      s   8.5
3     3      s   9.0
4     4      s   9.5
5     5      s  10.0
6     6      s  10.5
7     7      s  11.0
8     8      s  11.5
9     9      s  12.0
10    1 strat1   0.0
11    2 strat1   0.0
12    3 strat1   0.0
13    4 strat1   0.0
14    5 strat1  -0.5
15    6 strat1  -1.0
16    7 strat1  -1.0
17    8 strat1  -1.0
18    9 strat1  -1.0
19    1 strat2   2.0
20    2 strat2   1.5
21    3 strat2   1.0
22    4 strat2   0.5
23    5 strat2   0.0
24    6 strat2   0.5
25    7 strat2   1.0
26    8 strat2   1.5
27    9 strat2   2.0
```

Comment: Seems like you're mis-melting. I think you want `m_payoffs <- melt(payoffs, id= 1)`. You want your x-axis in one column and your y-axis in another column (with, in this case, a third column indicating the grouping of the different lines).

Comment: Yes. I tried that. But then how can i plot those 2 columns in ggplot ? It seems like both my x-axis values and y-axis are in the same column after this.

Comment: Oh, just realized you have a matrix. Use `m_payoffs <- melt(as.data.frame(payoffs), id= 1)`